# Is the image of the difference equal to the difference of the images?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Let $f: A → B$ be a function; $E, F ⊆ A.$ Is $f(E - F) = f(E) - f(F)$ ?

Answer (score 3):

The right hand side $f[E]-f[F]$ is always contained in the left hand side $f[E-F]$. The reverse inclusion is valid if and only if $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $f(x) = x^2$, $E=\mathbb{R}$, and $F=(0,+\infty)$.